# Laravel route planning

Tags: php, laravel, routes

My DB Structure is as following : 
1 `Domain` (superior category) has many `Categories`. 1 `Category` has many `Subcategories`. 1 Location has many `Subcategories`.

Example : 
`Domain` : IT, `Category` : Programming, `Subcategory`: WebDevelopment, `Location`: Texas.

When client enters to website, he has buttons with all Domains on the site.  Each button goes to Route : `Route::get('/{domain}', 'Website\DomainController@show')`

When he goes at this route, he have a list of all categories of that domain.
When client press one of that buttons, he is redirected to `Route::get('/{domain}/{category}', 'Website\CategoryController@show')`.
Here he takes a list of all subcategories.

Each subcategory has it's own button, that goes to route : 
`Route::get('/{domain}/{category}/{subcategory}', 'Website\SubcategoryController@show')`

At that page, user gets a big SVG map, with all regions of my country. All that "Locations" are stored in my Database table `Location` described above.
So, when user clicks at specific region, he is redirected to route :
`Route::get('/{domain}/{category}/{subcategory}/{location}', 'Website\LocationController@show')`

At this point, user gets a Google Map of that specific region, with `Maps Markers` from Database. When clicked on any marker, it must redirect to a view page of that subcategory, where is information like : `name, photo gallery, contacts, etc`.

I'm feeling like I planned not so good my routes. Do I need to refactor them, or give me please some ideas how can I name that route?

Basic logic in a nutshell :  User came to site, select `domain1`, redirected to page where are showed all `categories of domain1`. Selects `category3`. Now it is redirected to page where he have to select one of subcategories from `category3`. He selects `subcategory4 from category3`. Ok, now we know that he want smth like : `IT/Programming/WebDevelopment`. Now he can see a Map of entire country. He selects a region and get redirected to `It/Programming/WebDevelopment/London`. At this page he gets a google map of London, where are situated all `WebDevelopment` from London. Each `WebDevelopment` office has it's own Marker on the map. When click on specific marker, it must redirect to a view page of that WebDevelopment.

Comment: Usually, you will have lots of routes. But you should decide which ones you need - we cannot do that for you, how should we know each and every bit of your application?

Comment: @NicoHaase I need all that routes. The question is that, from my point of view and Laravel conventions, a show route for subcategory must look like 
`/{domain}/{category}/{subcategory}`. But that route is busy, because at this route user have to select a location where he wants to find it. 
So, the question is...how to change route conventions to get a clear route architecture?
Or what route structure to put for that route of show the `subcategory`?

Comment: Why don't you prefix the routes? `/domain/{domain}/category/{category}/subcategory/{subcategory}` might work